# SQL Server retrieving multiple columns with rank 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I will try to describe my issue as clearly as possible.

I have a dataset of unique 1000 clients, say ##temp1.

I have another dataset which holds the information related to the 1000 clients from ##temp1 across the past 7 years. Lets call this dataset ##temp2. There are 6 specific columns in this second dataset (##temp2) that I am interested in, lets call them column A, B, C, D, E, F. Just for information, the information that columns A, C, E hold is year of some form in data type float (2012, 2013, 2014..) and the information that columns B, D, F hold is ratings of some form (1,2,3,..upto 5) in data type float. Both year and ratings columns have NULL values which I have converted  to 0 for now.

My eventual goal is to create a report which holds the information for the 1000 clients in ##temp1, such that each row should hold the information in the following form,

```
ClientID | ClientName | ColA_Latest_Year1 | ColB_Corresponding_Rating_Year_1 | ColC_Latest_Year2 | ColD_Corresponding_Rating_Year_2 | ColE_Latest_Year3 | ColF_Corresponding_Rating_Year3.
```

ColA_Latest_Year1 should hold the latest year for that particular client from dataset ##temp2 and ColB_Corresponding_Rating_Year_1 should hold the rating from Column B corresponding to the year pulled in from Column A. Same goes for the other columns.

The approach which I have taken so far, was,

1. Create `##temp1` as needed
2. Create `##temp2` as needed
3. `##temp1 LEFT JOIN ##temp2` on client ids to retrieve the year and rating information for all the clients in `##temp1` and put all that information in `##temp3`. There will be multiple rows for every client in `##temp3` because the data in `##temp3` is for multiple years.
4. Ranked the year column (B,D,F) partition by client_ids and put in in `##temp4`,

What I have now is something like this,

```
Rnk_A | Rnk_C | Rnk_F | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF | Client_id | Client_name
2     |    1  |    1  |   0  |  0   |   0  |   0  |  2014 |  1  |   111 | 'ABC'
1     |    2  |    1  | 2012 |  1   |   0  |   0  |  0    |  0  |   111 | 'ABC'
```

My goal is

```
Rnk_A | Rnk_C | Rnk_F | ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF | Client_id | Client_name
1     |  1    |   1   |  2012|  1   |  0   |  0   |  2014|  1   | 111 | 'ABC'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "_Both year and ratings columns have NULL values which I have converted to 0 for now_" Don't do that! `NULL` and `0` are fundamentally different. If you arbitrarily map one to the other, you're losing information because you can no longer tell the two ***different*** cases apart. (Just note, this is general advice, you might get away with it in your specific case - but then you're just lucky. Don't get into what is a bad habit, because really: ***you don't need to do that*** provided you just simply handle NULLs correctly.)

Comment: Do you have any duplicates _per client_ for any of your A, C, E columns. This is a very important consideration for your solution. (And PS: In general you should show the query you've attempted that isn't quite working.)

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you don't have any duplicates per client in columns A, C, E. If you do have duplicates you'd need to find a way to differentiate them and make the necessary changes.

The hurdle that you've failed to overcome in your attempt (as described) is that you're trying to join from `temp1` to `temp2` ***only once*** for lookup information that could come ***from 3 distinct rows*** of `temp2`. This cannot work as you hope. You must perform separate joins for each pair [A,B] [C,D] and [E,F]. The following demonstrates a solution using CTEs to derive the lookup data for each pair.

```
/********* Prepare sample tables and data ***********/
declare @t1 table (
    ClientId int,
    ClientName varchar(50)
)

declare @t2 table (
    ClientId int,
    ColA datetime,
    ColB float,
    ColC datetime,
    ColD float,
    ColE datetime,
    ColF float
)

insert into @t1
select  1, 'Client 1' union all
select  2, 'Client 2' union all
select  3, 'Client 3' union all
select  4, 'Client 4'

insert into @t2
select  1, '20001011', 1, '20010101', 7, '20130101', 14 union all
select  1, '20040101', 4, '20170101', 1, '20120101', 1 union all
select  1, '20051231', 0, '20020101', 15, '20110101', 1 union all
select  2, '20060101', 2, NULL, 15, '20110101', NULL union all
select  2, '20030101', 3, NULL, NULL, '20100101', 17 union all
select  3, NULL, NULL, '20170101', 42, NULL, NULL

--select  * from @t1
--select  * from @t2

/********* Solution ***********/
;with MaxA as (
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ClientId ORDER BY t2.ColA DESC) rn,
    t2.ClientId, t2.ColA, t2.ColB
    from    @t2 t2
    --where   t2.ColA is not null and t2.ColB is not null
), MaxC as (
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ClientId ORDER BY t2.ColC DESC) rn,
    t2.ClientId, t2.ColC, t2.ColD
    from    @t2 t2
    --where   t2.ColC is not null and t2.ColD is not null
), MaxE as (
    select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.ClientId ORDER BY t2.ColE DESC) rn,
    t2.ClientId, t2.ColE, t2.ColF
    from    @t2 t2
    --where   t2.ColE is not null and t2.ColF is not null
)
select  t1.ClientId, t1.ClientName, a.ColA, a.ColB, c.ColC, c.ColD, e.ColE, e.ColF
from    @t1 t1
        left join MaxA a on
            a.ClientId = t1.ClientId
        and a.rn = 1
        left join MaxC c on
            c.ClientId = t1.ClientId
        and c.rn = 1
        left join MaxE e on
            e.ClientId = t1.ClientId
        and e.rn = 1
```

> If you run this you may notice some peculiar results for Client 2 in columns C and F. This is because (as per your question) there may be some NULL values. ColC date is "unknown" and ColF rating is "unknown".

My solution preserves `NULL` values instead of converting them to zeroes. This allows you to handle them explicitly if you so choose. I commented out lines in the above query that could be used to ignore NULL dates and ratings if necessary.

Comment: Thanks Craig! This is exactly what I was looking for. And to answer your question, I do not have any duplicates in my ##temp1, or t1 in your case. I have 1000 unique clients in my ##temp1. However, multiple records are present for these clients in my ##temp2 as ##temp2 holds the data for these clients over the past 7 years.